# jqGrid when prototype functions used

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm using prototype functions in my code. If  i add a select box in the jqgrid, it adds an extra option at the bottom with value as a function.
If i remove the prototype functions, it works fine then.

Sample prototype function in my code:

```
ConfigureFilterClass.prototype.buildFilter = function(){
// my code
}
```

Below  gets added to the select box as an option in jqGrid!

```
<option role="option" value="diff">
 function (a) {
  return this.filter(function(i) {
  return !(a.indexOf(i) &gt; -1);
});
}
</option>
```

Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow got the solution for my problem:

Actually i have used Array.prototype functions in my code.And the jqgrid doesnot support the direct Array.prototype functions.So i had to make these functions through some prototype function class and then make the function through it.

Doing this way the jqGrid works fine.

Example:

`Array.prototype.diff=function({
//mycode
});`

`Array.prototype.unique=function({
//mycode
});`

These functions comes in jqGrid select option with "diff" and "unique" as values.

So i changed it to:

`function SomeclassName{

}`

`SomeclassName.prototype.diff=function{
//mycode
};`

`SomeclassName.prototype.unique=function{
//mycode
};`

Then the jqGrid works fine.

Thanks.